# How to get values from one column and convert it into two columns SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a SQL Tabel which contains 3 columns (id, size, grade, unit_price) as shown in this picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nuIz.png):

[image: SQL Table Image]

I want to display this table in HTML in the form of:

```
size | grade 40 price | grade 60 price
```

as shown in the below image:

[image: html table required]

Comment: Hello! What have you tried? What is not working? Please give us some more details

Comment: id1 and id6 are the same size and grade but with different prices?

Comment: i have no idea how to do this

Comment: yes each grade have same sizes but different prices

Comment: You could ORDER BY size and then grade, then retrieve rows two at a time and merge the contacts for your display table.

Comment: You really should read up on "Database normalisation" though, there's a lot of repetition in that table that should not be there. It might also make this task more simple if you had a table that contained all your sizes, and a linked table that contained the prices for each grade of that size.

Comment: Can you guide me little more?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
select size,
       max(case when grade = '40 Grade' then unit_price end) as price_40,
       max(case when grade = '60 Grade' then unit_price end) as price_60
from t
group by size;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database should be normalized.
2. For example, you should have at least a product_id to know, to which exactly product, the information refers to. In this case. The only thing that refers the same product - is the same size, which is string, and which is not a good practice.

Here is a code that should work for your case, but I recommend to change your DB schema

```
SELECT
    p1.size,
    p1.unit_price AS price_grade_40,
    p2.unit_price AS price_grade_60

FROM products AS p1

LEFT JOIN products AS p2
       ON p1.size = p2.size
      AND p2.grade = 'Grade 60'

WHERE p1.grade = 'Grade 40'
```